# How to animate the rotation and size of a container/image to be full screen (manual portrait to landscape)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

struggling with a Flutter animation issue...

I am trying to animate the rotation of a container 1/4 turn and then resize the container by swapping width and height to achieve full screen.

I created a small app to illustrate. The goal is for the red container to take up the
whole screen but it is being constrained. Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to remove that constraint?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FlutterAnimations(),
    );
  }
}

class FlutterAnimations extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FlutterAnimationsState createState() => _FlutterAnimationsState();
}

class _FlutterAnimationsState extends State<FlutterAnimations>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1600),
    );
    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    timeDilation = 3.0;

    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return RotationTransition(
      turns: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: .25).animate(_controller),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: _controller.value * screenHeight,
            height: _controller.value * screenWidth,
            child: FlutterLogo()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[animation rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBChq.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can study the constraints here: [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints)

The problem of your case is that **The original Width constraints is screenWidth**

That means you can only use screenWidth as your child widget height after it rotated 90 degree

The original code will be similar to:

```
return ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(
    maxHeight:MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, 
    maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  ),
  child: RotationTransition(
  ...
```

You can always break the constraints rule by using **OverflowBox**

```
return OverflowBox(
  maxWidth: screenHeight,
  child: RotationTransition(
  ...
```